# Monodevelop will not start in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: monodevelop

I am trying to install MonoDevelop in Ubuntu 18.04 , but after installing monodevelop the ide don't starts. I try to run it from the command line and I get no output and no splash screen. Just nothing happens.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptoms here. New installation; had installed first mono-devel and mono-complete (both useless).

This fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```